# Finding the success and failure count from a database

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My db entries look like this

```
[
{
_id : ObjectId("5839d639c7475e3gr32fcf86")
email : abcd@gmail.com
status : failed
}
{
_id : ObjectId("5839d639df7475e3gr32fcf86")
email : efgh@gmail.com
status : success
}
]
```

I want to group by the email id's and create an output table with three columns, Email, SuccessCount and failCount.

My code currently looks like this (**not working**)

```
db.getCollection.aggregate([
{$group: 
    {_id: "$email", successCount : {$sum : 1, $status : success }, failCount : {$sum : 1, $status : failed} }
}
],
{
allowDiskUse: true
})
```

I am trying to add the `"status": success` inside the successCount and with the $sum as well but none of them are working. Where am I going wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: share proper document structure. The one you shared isn't valid. Is it a single doc, multiple docs, array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can also do same in single group stage

```
 db.mycol.aggregate({
        $group: {
            _id: '$email',
            sucessCount:{$sum:{$cond:[{$eq:["$status","success"]},1,0]}},
            failCount:{$sum:{$cond:[{$eq:["$status","failed"]},1,0]}}
        }
    })
```

Comment: The counts are all showing 0 for both success and failed for all the email addresses.

Comment: are you sure that status field contains only "success" and "failed" value only?

Comment: Yes, I checked it twice. Not able to figure out what I am missing here.

Comment: db.mycol.aggregate({
        $group: {
            _id: {email:'$email',status:"$status"},
            count:{$sum:1}
        }
    },
    {
      $group:{
       _id:"$_id.email",
       counts:{$push:{status:"$_id.status",count:"$count"}}
      }
    })
can you check with this?

Comment: Its getting timeout after searching for a long time.

Comment: Okay its working now. Your first code. It was purely my mistake. I missed a part of the code. Sorry and thanks :)

Comment: [{ 
    "_id" : "x@fb.com", 
    "counts" : [
        {
            "status" : "success", 
            "count" : 1.0
        },
        {
            "status" : "failed", 
            "count" : 2.0            
        }
    ]
}] output is like this . you are missing something

Comment: both are working but First one is better in case if you know that status is always "success" or "failed"

Comment: Yes.. I just checked. They are. thank you so much again. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

You can try following query

```
db.mycol.aggregate({
    $project: {
        email: '$email',
        success: {
            $cond: { if: { $eq: ['$status', 'success'] }, then: 1, else : 0 }
        },
        failed: {
            $cond: { if: { $eq: ['$status', 'failed'] }, then: 1, else : 0 }
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: { _id: '$email', success: { $sum: '$success' }, failed: { $sum: '$failed' }
    }
})
```